# In Unit.AssemblyHooks class method TestRunnerManager.OnTestRunStart() could not load current project assembly , but dll exist in executing folder

Tags: c#, specflow

I have trouble in NUnit.AssemblyHooks class.
Method TestRunnerManager.OnTestRunStart() cant get the current assembly, but one in Environment.CurrentDirectory.

Any suggestions?

```
// <auto-generated />
#pragma warning disable

using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Diagnostics;
using global::NUnit.Framework;
using global::TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[GeneratedCode("SpecFlow", "3.5.14")]
[SetUpFixture]
public class Smb_UITests_SpecFlow_NUnitAssemblyHooks
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public void AssemblyInitialize()
    {
        var currentAssembly = typeof(Smb_UITests_SpecFlow_NUnitAssemblyHooks).Assembly;        
        TestRunnerManager.OnTestRunStart(currentAssembly);
```

> OneTimeSetUp: System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'UITests.SpecFlow.dll, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Great thank!

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question as well?

Comment: Is `TestRunnerManager` a class that you wrote, or a library class from a DLL or NuGet package?

Comment: Thank to all!
The class SpecFlow_NUnitAssemblyHooks creating automatically. 
If I right remember my problem solved by write in .cproj such section:

`<EmbeddedResource Include="specflow.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</EmbeddedResource>`